# Was Freemasonry such a big problem in 1980s UK policing?

Tags: historical-accuracy, ashes-to-ashes, the-gold

One of the themes of [*The Gold*](https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/drama/the-gold-bbc-release-date/) is that the police of 1983 have [many members in influential Masonic lodges](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2023/feb/18/fact-of-fiction-the-truth-behind-tv-dramas-bbc-the-gold-brinks-mat), and that this played a role in protecting some criminals and also corrupt police. The main detective character, Boyce, insists on 'no freemasonry' in his special task force.

[Freemasonry also plays a subversive and corrupting role](https://life-on-mars.fandom.com/wiki/Series_2:_Episode_2_(Ashes_to_Ashes)) in the 1980s-set police drama series *Ashes to Ashes*.

Freemasonry and corruption in the police seems to be a recurrent theme in UK-based police dramas set in the 1980s - but was it as big and far-reaching an issue as the dramatists portray?

Comment: Is the show set in the UK? I wouldn’t be surprised if freemasonry is different in the UK vs USA, Canada, Australia, etc. I’m guessing UK because that’s the only place I’ve ever heard of “flying squads”.

Comment: Related: https://theconversation.com/amp/the-freemasons-no-longer-have-significant-influence-in-the-british-police-89681   https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/revealed-how-gangs-used-the-freemasons-to-corrupt-police-9054670.html?amp

Comment: @Todd Thanks, updated question to make UK setting more obvious.

Comment: The parallel scare in the US was Satanists, who were eventually replaced by evil clowns.  The latter took over the government at one point.

Answer (score 33):

It was a **perceived** problem.
Freemasonry was blamed for everything in the 80s.  There were books about it. It was in all the red-top newspapers. They were demonised as being some evil secret club where to be a member meant you subsumed yourself as if to some Eyes Wide Shut/Wicker Man type devil-worshipping cult, where they probably drank the blood of goats & burned small children in large wicker statues. Once you were high enough up the hierarchy, the world opened up for you like some all-pervading secret underground society who held  all the purse strings & had the key to every door. Think what Dan Brown made of his Illuminati etc in the DaVinci Code, except these people lived just next door & you couldn't tell who was a member, unless you knew the funny handshake.

The trouble is, the freemasons could never respond; it's against their 'charter' or whatever they have, so the journos speculated to their heart's content.

You only need to add to this that both the police & the 'crims' must now, of course, all be in the very same lodge [and probably play golf together at the weekend] & you have a lot of room for the wildest speculation, with no fear of anyone ever actually disabusing you.

My father in law was at one time [not in the UK, though he is British] the second highest ranking member in his country's entire Freemasons society. Literally only one person senior to him.
He once explained this entire misconception to me quite concisely as a ***'load of old bollocks'***, but couldn't tell me any details either, beyond yes, they wear funny aprons & odd medallions and sashes - I've seen his & ordinary members of the public can visit Masonic halls to see some on display [I filmed a couple of nights in the big one in London for Assassin's Creed; they're really not hidden away]. Yes, they have really, really long ritual speeches for ceremonies which must be done from memory. He says he did well in the organisation mainly because he's good at remembering speeches.
No, goats & small children are quite safe, though they're not actually allowed in the building at all.

I think as a story element, to go with the press frenzy about it all at the time, you may as well 'blame the masons'. Everybody did.

Comment: +1 it was funny, i was in that same hall on a shoot, with a bunch of ex police, who hadn't been in the society and they had a lot of choice words for it.

Comment: Its still very much a perceived problem today, with it being demonised by the government as late as 1998 (when there were plans to force members of police forces to declare memberships) and 2014 (when there was a now-discredited report on how crime gangs were using Freemasonry to corrupt police forces).

Comment: The 90s BBC series Heartbeat had a few references to Masonic influence on policing in a rural 1960s constabulary.

Comment: I heard that the reason for the Freemason's secrecy was due to Hitler shipping known Freemasons off to the camps along with Jews, Romani, and homosexuals. During WWII (where the threat of Nazi invasion of the UK was high) the Freemasons, who had been quite open beforehand) decided to shroud everything in secrecy to protect themselves.

Comment: So it's basically Larping, except for old and rich people ?

Comment: dna - i know young and not-rich, and who are in the force, who are freemasons...

Comment: "You would say this ..." !

Comment: Not directly relevant here but theories and fears about the masons have a long history.  In the US there was even an [Anti-Masonic political party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Masonic_Party).

Comment: Freemasons were swearing oaths of secrecy long before the National Socialist German Workers’ Party was founded.
https://www.history.com/news/freemason-secrets-revealed
https://time.com/5877435/freemason-secrecy/

Comment: Ah, there's a difference between secrecy of the rites and "secrets" of the society, and secret as in concealing their membership of said society.

Comment: Maybe not so far off.   At one point in the initiation apparently you are supposed to be 'shot' with a gun loaded with blanks.  Look up 'masonic initiation shooting'.   Some guy in 2004 used his own gun, apparently by accident, and killed the initiate.  A guillotine was apparently a prop in the ceremony as well.  There are stories in 2012 and 2022 as well.  There are apprently a lot, dating back to Daniel Rees in 1737.

Comment: The son of a high-ranking free-mason would say this though...

Comment: The local one's near my old school, though everyone thought it was a synagogue. Its so secret... it has a fancy restaurant in it...

Comment: I don't think the problem with freemasonry was the ethos of the club itself, the problem was that it often drew together those, like police officers and criminals, whose close fraternising might have seemed improper to many if done more openly, and it often drew together those who had a penchant for corruption in the first place and whose attraction to the club was the opportunity for forging such corrupt links with the like-minded.

Comment: "*burned small children in large wicker statues*": in Scottish Rite Masonic Lodge, **no toddler!** (*only cats are allowed*).

Comment: @Moo The freemasons supposed alliance with some controversial political figures (like Bolsonaro) didn't help at all.

Comment: @Steve You're on-point. And, not only that, but there are several splinter Freemason groups that do things in their own way, oftentimes with no ties to the more traditional groups. My area has four distinct lodges with no relation to each other, with very different ideas, that are often figthting over members (because members = money). It's honestly quite fun to watch from the sidelines.

Comment: @JimmyJames aha, but you see, by revealing his secrets in a way that makes it impossible for me to prove or disprove their veracity he had in fact kept his secrets perfectly safe!

Comment: For what it's worth, the Freemasons' sworn enemy (or so I've heard) of Catholics, and their Knights of Columbus, get the same conspiracy theory nonsense attached to them, c.f. when people were convinced that Kennedy was a secret Vatican spy who was going to take over the United States via the presidency.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - this is just adding voice to the myriad speculative rumours the question hints at & doesn't help the answer in any way. Yours isn't the only one. That's the trouble when a question hits HNQ. The noise floor goes way up.

Comment: @Tetsujin: ^_^ I guess it's all a long form of "no, not really".

Comment: Whatever about the 1980s, the  [Operation Countryman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Countryman), 1978-82, investigation into corruption in the Met seems to have found some evidence of masonic ties: "over 250 police officers were forced to resign and many faced criminal charges after investigations revealed that police membership of particular Masonic lodges formed the nucleus of a criminal conspiracy." ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Countryman#cite_note-11)) . So it's not unreasonable to suppose such links may have continued through the 80s, albeit perhaps declining.

Comment: Also (though this is more by way of hearsay), the concern with masonry and the police was not so much baby-eating bacchanals but that they might put their vows to support fellow masons before their duty to uphold the law.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Those comments look like they'd be a good answer to the question